# What should I do after failing to replace my "arXiv" paper twice?

Tags: arxiv

I have a question regarding the submission process on arXiv. I previously submitted a paper and now I would like to update it using the "replace" feature. **However, despite attempting this process twice, my requests have not been executed and the paper remains unchanged.** I'm wondering what the best course of action is in this situation. Should I contact a specific department regarding this issue?

Any guidance or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Did you receive any message from the arxiv?

Comment: I haven't received any emails. When the expiration date is reached, the submission just disappears. I'm not sure if it's because I rearranged the order of the last two authors or not.

Comment: After submitting the change, did you receive a confirmation email from the arxiv? usually it arrives after a minute from submitting. The title should be something like "arXiv replacement submit/"

Comment: I just checked my mailbox. Surprisingly, there's nothing. However, before changing my arXiv email, I used to receive this kind of email. I'm not sure why.

Comment: What was the [submission status](https://info.arxiv.org/help/submit_status.html) after you replaced the paper? It is possible it was "incomplete".

Comment: I just tried it again and found submit button in the last page (I forgot to press). made a stupid mistake ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a submit button on the very last page (which you can only click once you downloaded the submission, either on this page or earlier after processing the latex sources). While this page looks like a final page, its point is to give you a last chance to (double-)check the submission before finally submitting it.  Only once you click this submit button, the submission is actually submitted.

Comment: the submit button will be there already if you view the submission at the "process" step (which is the recommended location to do this, even if you're submitting a pdf).

Comment: @Jake True, though this was actually included in what I wrote ;)

Answer (score 6):

If the submission is disappearing at the end of the expiration date, the most likely scenario is that your submission has never been fully submitted for replacement.

The first thing you should do is [contact arXiv via the support channel](http://arxiv.org/support/general_help) with the submission-id from any one of the replacements you've begun. If you no longer have them, you can reach out with the arXiv-id and we can check to see what's occurred to the individual replacements you're referring to. Without that information it's very difficult to be specific regarding what the problem is, but this basically boils down to one of two potential problems:

1. You haven't completed the replacement and your submissions are expiring; or:
2. You've completed your replacement, it's actually gone out and your browser is reloading the page from its cache.

[From our help pages](https://info.arxiv.org/help/replace.html): Replacements after number 5 should not be made more frequently than once per week. Versions ≤4 will appear in the mailings in the replacements section.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will try it again to figure out what is going wrong